# Ubuntu SDK needs LXD

Tags: qt, sdk, ubuntu-16.04

I need to create very simple GUI application in Linux. For this reason I have installed Ubuntu SDK on my Ubuntu 16. During first run it was trying to create LDX container. Why it needs this container? Got error below:

```
Generating a client certificate. This may take a minute... 
If this is your first time using LXD, you should also run: sudo lxd init 
Stopping containers: All containers stopped. Creating default network bridge .....
FAILED 
error: Creating the bridge failed with: not implemented 
---Task exited with errors, please check the output---
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu SDK is meant for developing applications for various devices. So it uses LXD containers to manage environments that correspond to the versions of the OS installed on these phones/tablets. I don't think that's your case.

To create a simple GUI application in Linux with Qt, you'll probably need to install QtCreator (or not) and packages like `qtbase5-dev`, `qtdeclarative5-dev`, `qml-module-qtquick-controls`. Then decide between the QtWidgets and the QtQuick/QML type of GUI.

Comment: So in order to build simple GUI I don't need ubuntu-sdk. But ubuntu-sdk contains also part of Qt ? So, if I need simple Qt I should install 4 packages you mentioned? What package should be installed for QtWidgets ?

Comment: Ubuntu SDK contains additional libraries/UI that were developed on top of Qt by Canonical Ltd for their GUI shell. Ubuntu SDK packages depend on Qt, so they install it. Just like `qtbase5-dev` that depends on QtWidgets (among other things). Run `apt-cache depends qtbase5-dev`.

Comment: After I have installed SDK none of 4 packages was needed to install. That means I have evrything for Qt? So how to run Qt then?

Comment: Follow some Qt or QtCreator tutorial. That's probably out of scope of the StackOverflow.